# In VB.NET I am adding an entry to a SQL Server database and it keeps adding double...?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to add an entry to a SQL Server database and it keeps adding double, and I'm not sure why. Also, when I try to show the data in a SQL Server datatable on a datagridview, it won't show all the columns! Although when I use the SQL Server Management Studio, it shows all the columns just fine.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Add sale
    Dim constring As String = "server=classified;database=classified"

    Dim myconnection As New SqlConnection(constring)
    myconnection.Open()

    Dim theQuery As String = "uspAddSale @Salesperson, @VIN, @Price, @MSRP, @CommissionRate, @CommissionEarned"
    ' ^^ Used to check if an identical entry already exists in the database.

    Dim repeatChecker As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(theQuery, myconnection)

    repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@Salesperson", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
    repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@VIN", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
    repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
    repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@MSRP", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text
    repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@CommissionRate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text
    repeatChecker.Parameters.Add("@CommissionEarned", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox6.Text

    Using reader As SqlDataReader = repeatChecker.ExecuteReader()
        If reader.HasRows Then
            ' User already exists
            MsgBox("PLEASE CHECK THIS MESSAGE BOX This sale already exists in the dealership's inventory.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Else
            reader.Close()

            repeatChecker.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Firs.BindGridSales()
            Firs.TabControl1.SelectTab(2)
            Firs.BindComboboxVIN()
            Firs.BindComboboxSalesperson()

            'Dim YearDisplay As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox7.Text)
            'Dim MakeDisplay As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox8.Text)
            'Dim ModelDisplay As String = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(TextBox9.Text)
            'Dim VINDisplay As String = TextBox10.Text.ToUpper

            'MsgBox("A " + YearDisplay + " " + MakeDisplay + " " + ModelDisplay + " with VIN # " + VINDisplay + " has successfully been added to the dealership's inventory.")
        End If
    End Using

    myconnection.Close()
End Sub
```

And here is my stored procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspAddSale] 
      @Salesperson varchar(100), 
      @VIN varchar(17), 
      @Price varchar(100), 
      @MSRP varchar(100), 
      @CommissionRate varchar(10), 
      @CommissionEarned varchar(10)
AS
    INSERT INTO Sales (Salesperson, VIN, [Sale Price], MSRP, [Commission Rate], [Commission Earned])
    VALUES (@Salesperson, @VIN, @Price, @MSRP, @CommissionRate, @CommissionEarned)
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with your vb code - your sproc is only doing inserts - no selects or updates.

Comment: What do you suggest?

Comment: use a different sproc, write a different one. its really hard to know what is available to you.

Comment: ExecuteReader causes your procedure to fire once, performing an insert. Because it has no rows, the 'else' portion of your 'if' fires, firing your procedure *again* via ExecuteNonQuery, hence your double-entries.

Comment: @DavidW Comparing with similar programs I have written in this package, I can see how this is most likely the issue. I'll get back to you in about 20 minutes. I think you are correct.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! Don't use `varchar` for things like price or commission earned !! Those are numbers - therefore use a **number datatype**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line:

```
Using reader As SqlDataReader = repeatChecker.ExecuteReader()
```

causes your insert procedure to fire once, inserting one record. It returns no records, hence the next few lines:

```
If reader.HasRows Then
    ' User already exists
    MsgBox("PLEASE CHECK THIS MESSAGE BOX This sale already exists in the dealership's inventory.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
Else
    reader.Close()
    repeatChecker.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

fall through to the '`Else`' portion, with '`reader.HasRows`' returning `false`. That causes the `.ExecuteNonQuery` to fire with the same text and parameters, repeating your insert.

The grid displays no rows because nothing in the procedure or in the code returns anything from the database to display.

Comment: Dear David,
My double entry issue is solved. 

What I meant by my second question was that when I manually enter data in (thru SQL directly) only 2 of the 5 columns will show up with information inside of them. The other 3 will show up but the info will be blank. In the datagridview.